# Pass props to children with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an app that runs a service before rendering any component, and that service makes several API calls, I get the data for example list of cars, trucks and bikes. Now I want to pass those props to children depending which route user clicks. If he visits /cars then I would send to this.props.children data for cars, and if he visits /bikes I would send bike data. How can I achieve that in MainComponent?

```
<ul>
   <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/bikes">Bikes</Link></li>
   <li><Link to="/cars">Cars</Link></li>
</ul>
{this.props.children}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use react-router to achieve this. Create two seperate components Bikes, Cars and route then links to these pages using a react-router definition as shown below.

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={MainComponent}>
             <Route path="bikes" component={Bikes}>
             <Route path="cars" component={Cars}>

        </Route>
   </Router>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: You misunderstood the quesstion, of course I have that already, the thing is how Im going to pass the data to /bikes through react-router's {this.props.children}, either way thanks

Comment: As I said, create two seperate components, Bikes and cars which render these props. and you need to route to these components then